# phpmyadmin, no vertical scroll bar on navigation panel

Tags: phpmyadmin

I recently installed phpmadmin 4.1.9. Unfortunately it is missing a vertical scroll bar in the navigation panel. I have tried it in Firefox 24 and IE 9 and both does not have it.
Even if you resize the window to a smaller one, it does not show a vertical scroll bar.

Can you please help me out or point me to a fix.

OS - redhat 5.10

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the navigation panel so you won't need the vertical scroll bar. 
Bring the cursor to the right edge of the navigation and you'll see the cursor changes. You can drag the right margin to resize the navigation panel.